# Review system with stars on click

Tags: javascript

So I have a review system based on stars, the stars work on width, there are 5 stars, so to fill 1 star you'd have to give to the respective element 20% width.  How can I make an onclick system that lets you add stars. I used this system for stars.

```css
.ratings {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #b1b1b1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.full-stars {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fde16d;
}

.empty-stars:before,
.full-stars:before {
  content: "\2605\2605\2605\2605\2605";
  font-size: 14pt;
}

.empty-stars:before {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #848484;
}

.full-stars:before {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px orange;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .full-stars {
    color: #ECBE24;
  }
}

<!--[if IE]>.full-stars {
  color: #ECBE24;
}

<![endif]-->
```

```html
<div class="ratings">
  <div class="empty-stars"></div>
  <div class="full-stars" style="width:70%"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: check [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/164933/jquery-hover-and-click-events-for-a-five-star-rating)

Comment: @Durga mine doesn't work on svg's..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the offsetX of the click on the element and compare it to the width of the ratings element to get an approximate percentage value and use that to update the styling.

Sample:

```js
var ratings = document.getElementsByClassName('ratings')[0];
var width = ratings.getBoundingClientRect().width;
ratings.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var deltaX = e.offsetX;
  var newRating = (deltaX / width) * 100;
  ratings.children[1].style.width = newRating + '%';

})
```

```css
.ratings {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #b1b1b1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.full-stars {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fde16d;
}

.empty-stars:before,
.full-stars:before {
  content: "\2605\2605\2605\2605\2605";
  font-size: 14pt;
}

.empty-stars:before {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #848484;
}

.full-stars:before {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px orange;
}


/* Webkit-text-stroke is not supported on firefox or IE */


/* Firefox */

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .full-stars {
    color: #ECBE24;
  }
}


/* IE */

<!--[if IE]>.full-stars {
  color: #ECBE24;
}

<![endif]-->
```

```html
<div class="ratings">
  <div class="empty-stars"></div>
  <div class="full-stars" style="width:90%"></div>
</div>
```

You can also normalise it lock on to fixed values like only full and half stars are allowed

```js
var ratings = document.getElementsByClassName('ratings')[0];
var width = ratings.getBoundingClientRect().width;
ratings.addEventListener('click', function(e){
 var deltaX = e.offsetX;
  var newRating = (deltaX/width) * 5;
  newRating = (Math.round(newRating * 2) / 2).toFixed(2) * 20;
  ratings.children[1].style.width = newRating + '%';
})
```

```css
.ratings {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #b1b1b1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.full-stars {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fde16d;
}

.empty-stars:before,
.full-stars:before {
  content: "\2605\2605\2605\2605\2605";
  font-size: 14pt;
}

.empty-stars:before {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #848484;
}

.full-stars:before {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px orange;
}


/* Webkit-text-stroke is not supported on firefox or IE */


/* Firefox */

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .full-stars {
    color: #ECBE24;
  }
}


/* IE */

<!--[if IE]>.full-stars {
  color: #ECBE24;
}

<![endif]-->
```

```html
<div class="ratings">
  <div class="empty-stars"></div>
  <div class="full-stars" style="width:90%"></div>
</div>
```